# Avoiding small sliver areas and Reducing pages in ArcGIS Pro Map Series?

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

Automating some map production.

**Current high level approach:**

- Have user providing an Area of Interest (AOI) as a polygon extent
- If AOI > Threshold Area size Then [generate a grid map](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/cartography/grid-index-features.htm)
- Use the origin of the AOI, create number of grids based upon PageUnit size for an A4 landscape template
- Then use this Grid to generate a Map Series.

**Problem**

There can be some pages that will only show a small 'sliver' of the intersecting AOI.  As crudely illustrated by the red rectangles in the below image:

[image]

What is a better approach to automate this kind of map production.  Make the assumption that the incoming AOI can be any size, any shape.  Scale and layout orientation are flexible.

The final multi-page map book needs to be easily understood by end-user, hence why we assumed a simple grid map would be sufficient.

I anticipate others will have encountered this issue before and found good workarounds

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's any easy solution to this or the duplicate.

Comment: You could try setting a negative margin size (if it is possible). But it might mess up all tiles.

Comment: Fair enough, missed the other Q.  One approach I am contemplating is calculating the rectangle around extent (similar-ish to convex hull) and then using that to create the grid index.  More likely things will fit.